# Can't run pip3 with sudo on centOs 7

Tags: python, centos, pip, sudo, wsgi

I have a wird problem. when i run pip3 commnad on centos 7 without sodo it works. so `pip3 --version` outpus this

```
pip 9.0.1 from /root/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

but when i run it with sudo like this `sudo pip3 --version` i get command not found error.

```
sudo: pip3: command not found
```

Can anybody help me with this? I want to install uswgi and it installation gets terminated when i'm not using sudo. this is the error

```
compilation terminated.

----------------------------------------
Command "/root/projects/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-
2usl184a/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
/tmp/pip-gv2qp3l0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-
externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
/root/projects/venv/include/site/python3.6/uwsgi" failed with error 
code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2usl184a/uwsgi/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo yum install python34-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
```

Comment: this works! can u explain what's happening and why this solves the problem?

Comment: You may have installed pip on the user profile but not installed it for root user, therefore sudo (root) has no command pip. Installing it this way will install it for root user.